# Cannot print in one line using Python3 and Python2.7

Tags: python

I tried both following ways to print in one line:

```
print (max,end=' ') # Python3
print max,          # Python2.7
```

However, `Pycharm` complains and gives me unresolved reference when using the first one. When I switch to Python 2.7 Interpreter and use `print max,` it gives this error:

```
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

I don't know what to do!! Appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually using a Python 2.7 interpreter when it gives the missing parentheses error? That looks like a Python 3 thing.

Comment: Python2 supports `from __future__ import print_function`

Answer (score 2):

Well, first Use

```
print(max,...) # NOTE: no space after the word print
```

The space in your question is being interpreted as `print (some_tuple)` or `print X` where `X` is a tuple, and then it thinks you are trying to use the python2 way of printing.

Second, not sure what `print(max,end=' ')` is supposed to do, but you can't define a variable in a print statement like that. What are you trying to print?

Comment: YES! it is because of the space!! I just fixed it . THANK YOU

Comment: @FriddyJoe yeah that is a subtle one. in python3 they throw an error when they detect a python2 way of printing, e.g., `print X`, which it detected here.

Comment: Even though it prints, it shows a red line error as `unresolved reference end ')' expected `. Do you know why?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Appreciate it

Comment: Python 3 won't throw a syntax error on `print (max,end=' ')`; while it's unusual, it's valid syntax. I don't know whether PyCharm will complain, but it won't throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Do `from __future__ import division` at the top of your file and use only the Python 3 style.